# Mismatch of requirements from JEDEC with recommendations Intel(Altera)

Tags: pcb-design, ddr, propagation

I am studying the workings of DDR memory, in particular the recommendations for PCB layout.
One of the intel [documents](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/an/an444.pdf) (Table 1–24; Page 70) has the following wording: "*Propagation delay of clock signal must not be shorter than propagation delay of DSQ signal at every device*"

However, if this is compared with the requirements from [JEDEC](https://www.jedec.org/sites/default/files/docs/JESD79-3F.pdf)(Registration required for reading,Table 69, page 175):
[image]
Where tCK is Average Clock Period = 8ns.

In the JEDEC standard I can clearly see the minus sign, which says that the DQS line is shorter. Is Intel(Altera) not DDR compliant or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Factors that contribute to the delay from one signal to another include
but aren't limited to:

- Difference in propagation delays of the PCB traces.
- Difference in propagation delays from the chip's transceivers to pads.
- Difference in when the outputs change.

The Intel app note says the chip adjusts the third, and the requirement
"Propagation delay of clock signal must not be shorter than propagation
delay of DSQ signal at every device" is for the adjustment to work.

Oh by the way, about the second factor.  With DDR3 being the standard of
an interface, what's specified is the times when the signals reach the
RAM chip's pads, so you don't have to worry about different propagation
delays from the RAM chip's pads to its transceivers.  However, some
FPGAs have different propagation delays from transceivers to pads, and
you need to account for that.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the negative time tdqss relative to the rising edge tCK, indicates that this gap is assume at the controller level, but not due to the difference in track lengths?

Comment: Yes.  And please pay attention to your grammar.